# ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named parameter not bound : users]

Tags: java, spring, exception

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Post p WHERE p.id IN : users ORDER BY p.createdAt DESC")
List<Post> findAllPostByUserIds(@Param("users") List<Integer> userIds);
```

I'm trying to solve a problem when I tried to post on my react app. The problem is on the backend. I'm not sure what is the problem. I put the code snippet where the problem occurred. But feel free to ask me about what other code is needed to solve this issue.

Comment: Try remove space between colon and parameter name like this `... WHERE p.id IN :users`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was wondering what was wrong with my code.

Comment: But could you explain why the code has to remove the space? seems like weird jargon to me.

Comment: It is not a jargon it is a standard. JPQL / SQL queries are just strings. Those have to be parsed somehow. Every word of that string can be a table / column name, a keyword (e.g. from, having, etc.) or a placeholder of a named parameter. Just think about you have a named parameter called `having` which is also an SQL keyword. And you have a query like: `FROM Post p WHERE p.id > 100 and p.otherField = : having`. In this case `having` literal is a parameter name or a keyword? That's why you always have to specify exactly which is which. Hope it helps.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I’ll have to read up on that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.